# excel "insert line" causing error with target.offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have this simple bit of code that automates some dates and stuff when adding line items to a sheet. It works well, but when I insert a line in to the spreadsheet [right-click the line name > insert] an error occurs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim plusWeek
    plusWeek = Now() + 7

For Each cell In Target
    '========adds closed date, deleted date if status degenerates=========
    If cell.Column = 13 And cell = "Closed" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -2) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End If
    If cell.Column = 13 And cell = "In-Progress" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -2) = ""
    End If
    If cell.Column = 13 And cell = "Open" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -2) = ""
    End If

    '========adds date added if date is embty and description is not empty========
    If cell.Column = 8 And IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 0)) Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = Format(plusWeek, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Target.Offset(0, 5) = "Open"
    End If
    '========deletes date added if description is empty========
    'If cell.Column = 8 And IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 0)) Then
    '    Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    'End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

if I paste a line, add a line or delete a line, error 1004 occurs. The debugger highlights this line, but I can't understand where the error comes from.

```
 If cell.Column = 8 And IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 1)) And Not 
 IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 0)) Then
```

Comment: Just use `Target` instead of `Target.Offset(0,0), is the same thing`. I think that particular bit is trying to offset the entire row, but you can't offset anywhere else from the last column (even though the offset is 0). Also generally, if you are selecting entire rows, you might want to change your code to not loop through all cells in the Target (which is all your selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim plusWeek
    plusWeek = Now() + 7

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H:H,M:M"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo haveError           '<< make sure events don't get left turned off

    Application.EnableEvents = False  '<< turn events off
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        '========adds closed date, deleted date if status degenerates=========
        If cell.Column = 13 Then
            Select Case cell.Value
                Case "Closed": cell.Offset(0, -2) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
                Case "In-Progress", "Open": cell.Offset(0, -2) = ""
            End Select
        End If

        '========adds date added if date is embty and description is not empty========
        If cell.Column = 8 And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
            cell.Offset(0, 2) = Format(plusWeek, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            cell.Offset(0, 5) = "Open"
        End If
        '========deletes date added if description is empty========
        'If cell.Column = 8 And IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 0)) Then
        '    Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        'End If

    Next cell

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so very much for your kind assistance.

Comment: @cucaracha21  if the answer solved the problem kindly accept the answer.